# Как вызвать рандомную функцию в другой функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача: вызвать функцию, которая будет вызывать рандомную фунцию.
Не понимаю пока как это сделать

```
import random

def main():
   all_func = [func1(), func2(), func3()]
   get_random = random.choice(all_func)

def func1():
    return "Первая"

def func2():
    return "Вторая"

def func3():
    return "Третья"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

def main():
    all_func = [func1, func2, func3]
    get_random = random.choice(all_func)
    return get_random()

def func1():
    print('Первая')
    return

def func2():
    print('Вторая')
    return

def func3():
    print('Третья')
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Да, логично и просто. Функция - тот же объект, так и обрабатывается тут.

Comment: Но у меня всё равно не получается. Сейчас конкретный пример приведу в новом вопросе.